# wp_update_user() returning http 500 internal server error

Tags: users, 500-internal-error

I have created **custom php file** inside **template directory** with the name `confirm_email.php` in which user's status is updating when user ***click on confirmation link sent to users email.*** but when i am using ***wp_update_user()*** to update user_status from 0 to 1. But it is returning ***Http 500 internal server error.***

```
<?php
$temp_dir="https://property-penang.com/wp-content/themes/wpresidence";

$url= $temp_dir."/confirm_email.php?id=".$_REQUEST['id']."&key=".$_REQUEST['key']."&type=return";
if(isset($_REQUEST['type'])){

$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $_REQUEST['id'], 'user_status' => 1) );

if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    // There was an error, probably that user doesn't exist.
    echo "Error is here";

} else {
    // Success!
    echo "User Email confirm";
}   

    }

else{

        $message="Username:".$_REQUEST['name']."
    Click on below link to confirm your email;
    ".$url;

    $subject="Email confirmation Link";
    $headers = "From: wordpress@property-penang.com" . "\r\n";

if(mail($_REQUEST['email'],$subject,$message,$headers)){
     echo "1";  
    }
else{
         echo "0";
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to load confirm_email.php directly? Then you're using WordPress functions despite not loading WordPress. You should handle this functionality through hooks, not its own file.

Comment: Surely if you turn on PHP Debugging it will give you a more specific error to go off of.